# Panel Flickering with Pictureboxes

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, panel, flicker

I need a way to avoid Flickering on a panel, I've made a lot of similar questions here and all around the world trying to asking to experts, I've tried a lot of tricks, extended panels, createparams, controlstyles, lost a lot of time, wasted time learning things that will don't work... I'm months trapped in this point.

...Nothing of that really works as expected, the best "Flicker-Reducer" I found is the "Createparams" override sub, but that method makes any Form/App x20 times more slower any operation of a Form, I don't want to loose flickering if that means loose application performance too (At least not if is the same negative point of performance of CreateParams).

In this video you can see my Test form with a 50% transparent panel where inside has pictureboxes with background images set to "Zoom" layering, when I scroll up or down I get a lot of flickering.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIBDTMjrDd4&feature=youtu.be

I use the "CreateParams" method, really you won't see what happens with the flicker of my panel if I don't use "CreateParams", really scary.

This is the panel when is not flickering:

[image]

And this is the panel in a moment where it is Flickered:

[image]

Here is the complete class:

```
It is a Windows Form proyect
VS2012
Framework 3.5
On Windows 7 x64
Application Visual Styles is ON
Double Buffer is ON
Panel and pictureboxes are default controls
```

(I think no need to say I've tried all the possible visual and environment configurations that people said me to forget forever the flickering.)

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim Scroll_Position As Int32 = 0
    Dim Button_Down_Is_Pressed As Boolean = False
    Dim Button_Up_Is_Pressed As Boolean = False
    Dim WithEvents Progressive_Scroll_Timer As New Timer
    Dim SmallChange As Int32 = 5
    Dim Largechange As Int32 = 10

    ' Sub which reduces the Flickering, but this sub makes x20 times slower any operation of any Form/Application.
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H2000000
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property 'CreateParams

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0)
        ' Me.TransparencyKey = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0)
        Panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum = 999999999
        Progressive_Scroll_Timer.Interval = 50
        Panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(150, 0, 0, 0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseHover
        sender.focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Progressive_Scroll_Timer.Tick
        If Button_Down_Is_Pressed Then
            Scroll_Down(SmallChange)
        ElseIf Button_Up_Is_Pressed Then
            Scroll_Up(SmallChange)
        Else
            sender.stop()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Scroll_Up(ByVal Change As Int32)
        Scroll_Position -= Change
        Panel1.SuspendLayout()
        Try : Panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = Scroll_Position : Catch : Scroll_Position += Change : End Try
        Panel1.ResumeLayout()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Scroll_Down(ByVal Change As Int32)
        Scroll_Position += Change
        Try : Panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = Scroll_Position : Catch : Scroll_Position -= Change : End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Down_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseDown
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            Button_Down_Is_Pressed = True
            Progressive_Scroll_Timer.Start()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Up_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseDown
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            Button_Up_Is_Pressed = True
            Progressive_Scroll_Timer.Start()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Down_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseUp
        Button_Down_Is_Pressed = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Up_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseUp
        Button_Up_Is_Pressed = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseWheel
        If Panel1.Focused Then
            Select Case Math.Sign(e.Delta)
                Case Is > 0 : Scroll_Up(Largechange)
                Case Is < 0 : Scroll_Down(Largechange)
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Please, uplad a while demo solution that you showed on YouTube.

Comment: The code that you provided is missing important parts.

Comment: @Ark-kun I've posted the full class, there is not more code in the solution (only the image resources and that), anyways here is the complete solution: http://elektrostudios.tk/WindowsApplication4.rar   thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Oliver, it is the WS_CLIPCHILDREN window style constant. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `Panel`'s `AutoScroll` property to `true`. Without this the scrolling doesn't seem to work.
Add the `DoubleBufferedPanel` class that inherits from the `Panel` class and sets the `.DoubleBuffered` property to true:

```
Public Class DoubleBufferedPanel
    Inherits Panel

    Public Sub New()
        DoubleBuffered = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now go to the hidden `InitializeComponent` sub (right-click on the `Panel1` variable and click `Go To Definition`). Replace `Panel` type with `DoubleBufferedPanel` where needed (two places):

```
Me.Panel1 = New WindowsApplication4.DoubleBufferedPanel()
....
Friend WithEvents Panel1 As WindowsApplication4.DoubleBufferedPanel
```

The flickering should stop (though there are still some other effects).
Remove the `CreateParams` to increase speed.

P.S. Overall, this is not a very good idea (moving complex half-transparent images). Why don't you use something like `ListView`? Why don't you move the images yourself without using `Panel`? If you want the best speed, just draw images on your form (`.BackgroundImage`) using `Bitmap` and `Graphics` classes.

P.P.S. There seems to be some serious bug with programmatically scrolling the `Panel` with `.AutoScroll = true`. I had to double-assign the scroll values to prevent serious jittering. I've isolated the case an will submit a bug report to Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks but is not a factible solution for me, like I said at the first time I've tried a lot of "boublebuffered panels" and other "tricks" that really does nothing, the usage of crateparams was only a example that I would show, createparams usage is not valid for me because the performance deceleration that causes in the application (I've made a lot of speed tests in months)

Comment: And the reason why I can't use GDI is because I need to insert controls with events inside the panel, I mean for example I need to make click in a PictureBox and then call the "click" event handler... I can't do that if I write a bmp image. but thanks for your answer!

Comment: Oh... I forget one thing: I don't know why you refered to the Listview, can you explain me please? If I use the panel is 'cause is a container for controls, the Liistview is not, also I use Panel 'cause the "AutoScroll" vertical bar is easy to manage instead writting a custom scrollbar. PS: Sorry 'cause my english and the little spam

Comment: I've wrote and tested the code myself and it **worked** - the flickering was gone. Have you tried my code?

Comment: of course I've tried, with and without createparams, without createparams the flickering is scaring, maybe you don't tested it in the same circunstances like I have (panel with pictureboxes and inside the pictureboxes each have a background image)

Comment: I've tested the project that you've uploaded. First thing I did was to remove `CreateParams`. The panel flickered a lot, like on your screenshot. Then I've written `DoubleBufferedPanel` and replaced the `Panel` in `InitializeComponent`. The flickering stopped completely. There was some "jello effect" though (the transparent parts of the `PictureBox`es move, retaining the underlying background for some small time), but it wasn't nearly as bad as flickering, because there was no white or grey - just the slightly displaced green background.

Comment: then maybe I did something bad when folowwing your steps, can you upload the project please?

Comment: I guess I missed saying that I set the `Panel.AutoScroll` to `true`. There was also the problem with mouse wheel scrolling (which is not bound by the `.LargeChange`). I've fixed it too. Anyways, there seem some serious bug with programmatically scrolling the `Panel`. I've found the workaround and updated my answer. Here is the complete flicker-free project: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=E4ECA4072D08CEE5!2873&authkey=!AGhzXoxqSt7eFPs . There is some jello, but I don't think that you can fix that with common controls without just drawing everything yourself.

Comment: P.S. You should also consider resizing the images. P.P.S. There is the `VScrollBar` control which you can use for making your own image scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

Use a complexed `class` that represents the `panel` and it's content, then paint(`GDI+`) that onto a `Picturebox` would render nicely. I have done several projects like this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you explain a little more all the things you said? Really I'm not much advanced in VBNET programming to do all of that without taking an example, but you've said "I have done several projects like this" maybe you can post a code-example from one of your projects?, anyways thanks again.

Comment: A `class` is just another `object`, this time you define it's `properties`. Then, in your case, you will need a collection of that class - `List(Of T)`. In your form you iterate the collection in the paint event. As for the scrolling part you can even check the Location.y of your class object and not paint it if it's too high or too low. `Rectangles` are great structures to use for drawing borders or to encase the images. Heck I even paint the scrollbars when using `GDI+`. It is hard to tell you everything you will need in one post.

Answer (score 3):

You might set Form's `DoubleBuffered` Property to `True`

**Edit :**

I think you don't need Timer.
So, Your modified code would be somewhat like this :

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim Scroll_Position As Int32 = 0
    Dim SmallChange As Int32 = 5
    Dim Largechange As Int32 = 10

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0)
        ' Me.TransparencyKey = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0)
        Panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum = 999999999
        Panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(150, 0, 0, 0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseHover
        sender.focus()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Scroll_Up(ByVal Change As Int32)
        Try
            Scroll_Position -= Change
            Panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = Scroll_Position 
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Scroll_Down(ByVal Change As Int32)
        Try
            Scroll_Position += Change
            Panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = Scroll_Position 
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Down_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseDown
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            scrollDown(smallChange)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Up_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseDown
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            scrollUp(SmallChange)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseWheel
        If Panel1.Focused Then
            Select Case Math.Sign(e.Delta)
                Case Is > 0 : Scroll_Up(Largechange)
                Case Is < 0 : Scroll_Down(Largechange)
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

This might not be the solution but this is an effort from my side.

Comment: Thanks but it is full of errors/exceptnions, you try to use it after editing? thanks anyways.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to remove some lines. Now it should work. And the code isn't tested. Just try to clean up the errors and if you have any other problems feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

put this in your form load

```
' to remove flick
Dim aProp As PropertyInfo = GetType(Panel).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
        aProp.SetValue(Panel7, True, Nothing)
```

replace Panel7 with the name of your control with background image.